# jQuery how to get indexed text value of <select> form field and and apply min max lengths to input textbox

Tags: jquery, text, min, maxlength

I have an indexed select list (goes up to ~5 instances, from 1 to 5) as follows:

```
<div>
<label for="ccType[1]">Credit Card Type</label>
<select name="ccType[1]" id="ccType[1]" class="jq__creditCardTypeChange">
<option value="0">No Card Selected</option>
<option value="1">American Express</option>
<option value="2">Discover</option>
<option value="3">MasterCard</option>
<option value="4">Visa</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And I have a corresponding indexed textbox (matches select list instance) as follows:

```
<div>
<label for="creditCardNumber[1]">Credit Card Number</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="creditCardNumber[1]" id="creditCardNumber[1]" class="jq__ccMinMaxLengthControl">
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to test if "American Express" is selected and set the min & max lengths on the creditCardNumber[] textbox to a certain value?

**Here is what I have started with:**

```
    $(document).on('change', '.jq__creditCardTypeChange', function(event) {

      var triggerID = event.target.id; // get the id that triggered the event

      var nStart = triggerID.indexOf('[') + 1;
      var nEnd = triggerID.indexOf(']');
      var i = triggerID.substring(nStart, nEnd); // get the index of the id that triggered the event

      var el = $('[id="' + event.target.id + '"]');

      if (el.val() == '1') {
        $('#creditCardNumber\\['+ i +'\\').attr('minlength', '15');
        $('#creditCardNumber\\['+ i +'\\').attr('maxlength', '15');
      }
      else {
        $('#creditCardNumber\\['+ i +'\\').attr('minlength', '16');
        $('#creditCardNumber\\['+ i +'\\').attr('maxlength', '16');
      }

    }); // end .on('change') Credit Card Number Length
```

So, I prefer to test for "American Express as the selected value rather than "1" because the index for AmEx could change at some point but the text itself would not change. And, any suggestions for improving the script performance would be a great learning experience for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text of the selected option like this:

```
var el = $('option:selected', this);
if (el.text() == 'American Express') {
    // rest of your code...
}
```

Also, using indexed `id` or `class` attributes leads to ugly code, such as you have dissecting the id string for square brackets. You can use DOM traversal to get related elements. If you can post a full HTML example I can give you more information on how to do this.

Comment: The HTML is both enormous and is dynamically produced from an open source tool. I am not fond of the indexed attributes either, but I don't know of any other way to produce the form. The select element, for example, is produced from a variable for() loop which is set and controlled by the user. Right now it is set to 5 but could be as little as 3 or as many as 10, etc. Thanks for you suggestion @RoryMcCrossan. I will give it a shot.